# check user has scrolled to the bottom in Jquery [code not working on Chrome]

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-ui

I wanted to check user has scrolled to the bottom of the page or not with jquery. I searched and find a solution which work perfectly on Microsoft Edge but it is not working fine on Google Chrome.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function() {   
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
   alert("bottom!");
}
});
});
```

```html
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 4000px">Scroll down!</div>
```

**Output in Microsoft Edge:** Perfect as I wants.

**Output in Google Chrome:** In Google Chrome when i scroll to bottom and again scroll to top then it works but I don't want this.

Comment: It is working fine in my google chrome through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working fine as expected on google chrome as well. Check this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function() {   
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
   alert("bottom!");
}
});
});
```

```html
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<div style="height: 4000px">Scroll down!</div>
```

If you want a pure javascript based solution then here you go :

```js
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        alert("you're at the bottom of the page");
    }
};
```

```html
<div style="height:5000px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility on all browsers, try [this method](https://j11y.io/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/)

```
function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight,
        D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight,
        D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight
    );
}
```

Replace `$(document).height()` by this function and it's all good

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == getDocHeight()) {
           alert("bottom!");
       }
});
```